# Sort column with date and time in R dataframe

Tags: r, date, time

I merged several other dataframes together. However, now the dates are no longer chronologically order (See photo). How do I order the dataframe based on the values of the 'Date' column?

[R dataframe output which I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB8IE.png)

I first tried to set the 'Date' column as index, but since the 'Date' column does not only have unique values, I can't.

Whenever I do:

```
new_df <- new_df[order(new_df$Date),]
```

it only sorts the dates based on their first value.

Next to that, sometimes there are multiple exact the same values for the 'Date' column. How can I make the index the same whenever the 'Date' column has the exact same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order` should be based on the converted to `Date` class

```
new_df$Date1 <- as.Date(new_df$Date, "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
```

If we want to keep the time part as well in ordering, use `as.POSIXct`

```
new_df$Date1 <- as.POSIXct(new_df$Date,format =  "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
```

and then do

```
new_df <- new_df[order(new_df$Date1),]
```

---

If we want to create a time series object, use `xts`

```
library(xts)
xts(new_df["Income"], order.by = new_df$Date1)
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
> str1 <- "Saturday, 12 Apr 2014, 18:00"
> as.Date(str1, "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
[1] "2014-04-12"
> as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
[1] "2014-04-12 18:00:00 EDT"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Is it also possible to make a new index, based on the Date1 column?

Comment: @Tobias you want two ordering?  Not clear

Comment: @Tobias Did you meant `library(xts)xts(new_df[, "Income"], order.by = new_df$Date1)`

Comment: @TarJae `parse_date_time(str1, "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")#
[1] "2014-04-12 18:00:00 UTC"` works as well

Comment: @TarJae I used `packageVersion('lubridate')
[1] ‘1.7.10’`

Comment: Not sure as it is working fine for me with the 'str1' i showed